# How to create lowdb in TypeScript(main.ts) Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, nosql

Creating Lowdb in `Javascript` working fine, I have searched in net, couldn't find proper(as per beginner's understanding) solution.

creating `lowdb` using `Js`

```
const low = require('lowdb')
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')
var customerpath = process.env.APPDATA+'/VEGFRUIT/Customer.json';
const cusadapter1 = new FileSync(customerpath)
const db = low(cusadapter1)
db.defaults({ customer: [{}]}).write();
```

how to convert above set of coding into `Tyepscript`?

Comment: What happens when you try to run this with TypeScript?

Comment: I got 
ts(15,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
src/main.ts(16,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.
src/main.ts(17,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'process'.

Comment: Try adding `@types/node` (`yarn add @types/node` for example

Comment: Shouldn't you be using something along the lines of `import { low } fro 'lowdb';`
`

Comment: i laready tried above one for import. But dont know what to do for const cusadapter1 = new FileSync(customerpath)
const db = low(cusadapter1)
db.defaults({ customer: [{}]}).write();

Comment: This is NodeJS code isn't it? Why exactly are you using this code in Angular?

Answer (score 3):

1) perform this command

```
npm install --save @types/lowdb
```

2) this brief example class shows how to use lowdb in a typescript way

```
import lowdb from "lowdb";
import { default as FileAsync } from "lowdb/adapters/FileAsync";

export class DbService {
    private db: lowdb.LowdbAsync<any>;

    constructor(){
        this.initDatabase();
    }

    private async initDatabase() {
        const adapter = new FileAsync("db.json");
        this.db = await lowdb(adapter);
    }

    private async SetSomeonesName(fullname: string): Promise<any> {
        await this.db.set("user.fullname", fullname).write();
    }
}
```